# Assigning Values to VBA Range Object

Tags: excel, vba, function, range

I am trying to assign initial values to a Range object.  I am using a loop, but I am not successful.  I desire rng2 to be the same size as rng1, and I wish to assign the value of "0" to all values in rng2, and use rng2 for further processing.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```vb
Function RangeParse(rng1 As Range) As Variant
  Dim rng2 As Range
  rng1Rows = rng1.Rows.Count
  Rem Initialize rng2 values
  For i = 1 To rng1Rows
    rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0
  Next i
  Rem
  RangeParse = rng1Rows
End Function
```

Comment: "not successful" doesn't tell us much about what happens when you run your code. Do you get an error? `rng2` isn't assigned to anything in your function, so that's something you need to fix.  Are you calling this from a worksheet?  If Yes then that will not work as a UDF - functions called that way can only return a value: they can't (eg) directly update other ranges.